# clear Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated in Terraform warning question

Tags: terraform, string-interpolation

We have been doing,

```
node_selector = var.node_group != null ? { “${var.node_group}” = true } : null
```

and in tfvars we will have, node_selector = “NODEGROUP2” And it works correctly.

Tflint is throwing a warning on it as below,
Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated in Terraform v0.12.14 (terraform_deprecated_interpolation)

Trying to understand what exactly its throwing warning and possible fixes?
Is it complaining on “${}” and I have to set to set it as var.node_group ?

setting the line as,

```
node_selector = var.node_selector != null ? { “var.node_selector” = true } : null
```

clear the tflint warning, however value is not being replaced for var.node_selector

May be I can make my question much simpler,
How do I make below work?

```
resource "random_pet" "this" {
  keepers = {
    "var.key" = "test"
  }
}

variable "key" {
  type        = string
  description = "test"
  default     = "ami_id"
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can use the new syntax: `node_selector = var.node_selector != null ? { var.node_selector = true } : null`.

Comment: I am also not sure what is the reason for using `=` sign after the variable, because I think that is not a valid comparison operator.

Comment: I solved it by,

keepers = {
    (var.key) = "test"
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "random_pet" "this" {
  keepers = {
    (var.key) = "test"
  }
}
```

Solved as above, had to put the var inside parenthesis.